# Select multiple ImageViews in activity.Is it possible?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-view

There are a lot of questions on Stackoverflow about "Selecting multiple images from gallery".But is it also possible to select multiple ImageViews in my activity and highlight the selected views.My ImageViews are in Horizontal scrollview.Please tell me how to do this beacause I didn't find something like 'Selecting multiple views' in documentation.

Comment: extend the ImageView class and set your logic there, then you can include it in a recycleview and handle selections from the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each ImageView i have unique key and by default all the values set to 0. When user click i change the status flag which is by default 0 in Hashmap value to 1 and also changed the background color of the view.It works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

use Custom listAdapters to Customize the listview as you wish, in you case multiple imageview selection